# Condition to terminate BFS

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have this assignment where given a list of tuples where each tuple contains 2 Strings like this :

- [ ("...","...") , ("...","...") , ("...","...") ... ]

I have to calculate the **shortest path** which will lead to an *extreme-string*.

An *extreme-string* is defined as a tuple of 2 strings where the first string is equal to the second string.

I know this might sound confusing so let me set an example.

Given :

- The list  [("0","100") , ("01","00") , ("110","11")]
- With indices 0,1,2
- The shortest path is : **[2,1,2,0]**
- The *extreme-string* is equal to : "110011100"

Step by step explanation :

- **Starting** with tuple of index 2 the initial string is : "110","11"
- **Appending** tuple of index 1 next string is : "11001","1100"
- **Appending** tuple of index 2 next string is : "11001110","110011"
- **Appending** tuple of index 0 final string is : "110011100","110011100"

So say you begin with tuple ("X","Y") and then you pick tuple ("A","B") then result is ("XA","YB").

The way I approached this problem was using BFS **which I already implemented** and sounds right to me but there is an issue I am dealing with.

If the input is something like :

- [("1","111")]

then the **algorithm will never terminate** as it will always be in the state "111..." - "111111111..." .

Checking for this specific input is not a good idea as there many inputs that can reproduce this result.

Having an upper bound for the iterations is also not a good idea because in some cases a finite result may actually exist after the iterations bound.

Any insight would be really useful.

Comment: How is an "extreme-string" defined?

Comment: @Hans Edited the question and the definition is in it.

Comment: As a side-note: A trivial precondition for a solution to exist would be that the input list needs at least one pair where the first string is shorter than the second one, and at least one pair where the first string is longer than the second; or, if all pairs of strings are of equal length, respectively, the solution can only be one or more of these. (But that does _not_ seem to help with the termination, AFAICS.)

Comment: This keeps puzzling me - have you had any new insights?

Comment: @Hans To be honest I could not find in time something that would resolve the input issue. As far as I know the BFS approach works perfectly and to my knowledge there will always be some *problematic* input.

Comment: @Hans according to my Theory of Computation professor the problem is semi-decidable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem described is semidecidable

Comment: this answer post could be improved with more detail and elaboration

Comment: @starball Well yes the answer could be impoved. That's just what the Theory of Computation professor revealed to us after the deadline had passed. Can't prove it myself but I just posted it so people do not waste their time.

Answer (score 0):

Since its an assignment I can't really solve it for you, but I'll try to give tips:

BFS sounds great to me as well.

One thing that differentiates the BFS from, say, DFS is that you place the elements of level N into the queue (as opposed to stack). Since queue is FIFO, you'll process the elements of Level N before elements at the level of N + 1. So this algorithm will finish (although might occupy a lot of memory).

The interesting part is what exactly you put into the queue and how you organize the traversal algorithm. This is something that I feel you've already solved or at least you have a direction. So think about my previous paragraph and hopefully you'll come to the solution ;)

Comment: While BFS, correctly applied, will find the shortest solution if there is any, I am not sure if the question was not about how to decide whether there is any solution, or rather: when to decide there won't be one. Since you can add strings ad infinitum, your queue will only grow and grow.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree that if there is no solution, the queue will grow infinitely and eventually will raise OutOfMemoryError (in java). I've assumed that the solution should exist and memory is not a concern in this task. @RookieCookie - please update the initial question with what you're asking here :)

Comment: @Mark Bramnik It's about this point  : *''when to decide there won't be one"* . Right now I am thinking of introducing a progress check. Each tuple has distance variable where it is defined as the absolute value of (stringOneLength - stringTwoLength).The BFS queue will have a maximum of that and a minimum as well and by comparing these 2 I might be able to deduct that there won't be a solution of finite length.